# Restricted number of parts and restricted size of parts - in C++

Tags: c++, math

I'm trying to re-build the following formula for 'Restricted number of parts and restricted size of parts' from the oeis.org [website](https://oeis.org/wiki/Restricted_compositions#n_parts_of_size_at_most_m):

It is supposed to give the "Compositions of n   ≤   k   ≤   m n into n parts, with size of parts not greater than m". I'm looping through the code until I get back a 0.

The expected outcome for C_3(3, 3) is 1,3,6,7,6,3,1 (as shown in the table on the site). I'm getting something like 1369121212

I just don't see where my code is wrong. I've looked at it for about 2 days now and still don't get it.

```
#include <iostream>

int C(int m, int n, int j)
{
    if (n == 0 && j == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (j < 0 || j > (m - 1) * n)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = j - ((m - 1) * n); i <= j; ++i)
    {
        sum += C(m, n - 1, i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int m = 3;
    constexpr int n = 3;

    int counter = 0;
    while (int result = C(m, n, counter++))
    {
        std::cout << result;
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please explain what the code is supposed to do without relying on external links

Comment: Okay, I added the description from the website - it's the best one I have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it's a recursive function for generating the number of restricted compositions of m elements into n parts of size at most m but the formula for this function seems to be incorrect.

The recursive formula should be:

```
C(m, n, j) = C(m, n-1, j-1) + C(m, n-1, j-2) + ... + C(m, n-1, j-m)
```

for a given value of n, the number of compositions of m elements into n parts of size at most m is equal to the number of compositions of m-1 elements into n-1 parts of size at most m, plus the number of compositions of m-2 elements into n-1 parts of size at most m, and so on, up to the number of compositions of 0 elements into n-1 parts of size at most m.

The base case of the recursion is when n = 0 and j = 0, in which case the function should return 1 (since there is only one way to compose 0 elements into 0 parts). The function should return 0 if either n < 0 or j < 0, since these cases are not valid.

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int C(int m, int n, int j)
{
    if (n == 0 && j == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 0 || j < 0)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = j; i >= j - m + 1; --i)
    {
        sum += C(m, n - 1, i);
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    constexpr int m = 3;
    constexpr int n = 3;

    int counter = 0;
    while (int result = C(m, n, counter++))
    {
        std::cout << result << " ";
    }

    std::cin.ignore();

    return 0;
}
```

check for j > (m-1)*n should be included:

```cpp
int C(int m, int n, int j)
{
    if (n == 0 && j == 0)
    {
        return 1;
    }
    if (n < 0 || j < 0 || j > (m - 1) * n)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = j; i >= j - m + 1; --i)
    {
        sum += C(m, n - 1, i);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: Wait, you're saying the formula on the website is wrong?

Comment: i've overlooked on that part, my bad!!

Comment: Alright, thank you very much! Now I can continue :)

Comment: You're saying that the recursion goes from j-1..j-m, but your code goes from j..j-m+1?